how to configure vite vue image path in template when having a base url prefix without mannually import the static image in script?
I have a image in root public folder in my vite vue3 project.
In order to deploy to github pages, for example in my repo called music-playing, I need to configure the base url in vite.config.js to toggle production mode and development mode. The problem is, github will automatically add a trailing path of my repo name so the absolute path in template
In  github production page it works fine, the path will be {github-domain}/{repo-name}/assets/img/song-header.png, and the image is served correctly on that url
In personal localhost this image wont be displayed, because this image is served on localhost:port/assets/img/song-header.png but vite is resolving it to localhost:port/music-playing/assets/img/song-header.png, I guess this wont work in future if i deploy it to a vps or other cloud.
Or, I can manually import the image into the script and use style directive to display it, but this means i need to mannually import the image every time in the souce code.
IS THERE A GENERAL SOLUTION TO THIS? I WANT VITE AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURE THE PATH IN BUILDING PROCESS
HERE IS THE CODE
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import VueDevTools from 'vite-plugin-vue-devtools'
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const isProduction = mode === 'production'
  return {
    base: isProduction ? '/music-playing/' : '/',
    plugins: [
      vue(),
      VueDevTools(),
    ],
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      },
    },
  }
})

in my vue template, it works well when i use absolute path
<div
  class="music-bg absolute inset-0 box-border h-full w-full bg-contain"
  style="background-image: url(/assets/img/song-header.png)"
/>

<template>
  <div
    class="music-bg absolute inset-0 box-border h-full w-full bg-contain"
    :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${bgImageUrl})` }"
  ></div>
</template>

<script>
import bgImage from '/assets/img/song-header.png';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      bgImageUrl: bgImage,
    };
  },
};
</script>

This will work by importing the image manually, that means all static image should be imported
By the way I have seen this answer and tried my solution like
<div
  class="music-bg absolute inset-0 box-border h-full w-full bg-contain"
  style="background-image: url(@public/assets/img/song-header.png)"
/>

BUT THAT ALSO DOEN'T WORK even configured the vite.config.js

resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    '@public': fileURLToPath(new URL('./public', import.meta.url)),
  },
},

